# cómo leer un texto en especifico desde una url en python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando leer un texto en especifico desde una url

Está es la url que quiero sacar el texto:
https://www.habbo.es/gamedata/external_flash_texts/f4fb96c8ffd2db6c2b1b3a44624df510a5dcfef4

el texto qué quiero obtener es

```
badge_desc_ADM=
badge_name_ADM=
```

desde un input con sólo escribir la palabra ADM aparezca los textos en especificos en este caso serian: Administrador y Placa de Administrador
pero no consigo hacerlo

Este es mi código que estoy usando ahora mismo:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

placa = input("Escribe el codigo de la placa: ")

data = urlopen("https://www.habbo.es/gamedata/external_flash_texts/f4fb96c8ffd2db6c2b1b3a44624df510a5dcfef4").read().decode('utf-8')

print(data)
```

Cómo lo deberia de hacer para que esto funcione?

Muchas gracias antemano!✌

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trabajando directamente en Python:

```
for linea in data.split('\n'):
    if linea.startswith("badge_desc_ADM=") or inea.startswith("badge_name_ADM="):
        key, value = linea.split("=")
        print(f"{key} {value}")
```

La página que haz leído queda completa en `data`, pero la quiero procesar línea por línea. Para eso uso `.split('\n')` que toma el texto y lo divide donde encuentra una nueva línea, produciendo una lista de líneas.

Dentro del `for` examino cada línea para ver si empieza con cualquiera de las dos llaves buscadas. Para eso uso `.startswith(cadena)`.

Para separar la llave del valor, uso `.split('=')`, que me devuelve los valores separados.

#### Demo

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = urlopen("https://www.habbo.es/gamedata/external_flash_texts/f4fb96c8ffd2db6c2b1b3a44624df510a5dcfef4").read().decode('utf-8')

for linea in data.split('\n'):
    if linea.startswith("badge_desc_ADM=") or linea.startswith("badge_name_ADM="):
        key, value = linea.split("=")
        print(f"{key} {value}")
```

produce:

```
badge_desc_ADM Placa de Administrador
badge_name_ADM Administrador

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yo creo que es mejor usar un modulo oficial como en la otra respuesta. Sin embargo, es bueno ver una alternativa hecha en Python puro. Eso si, startswith acepta una tupla de cadenas y devuelve True si la cadena empieza con alguna de ellas, quitando la necesidad de un "or" explicito. Otro detalle más. Solo por seguridad, pasaría a split maxsplit=1, por si el valor que viene después del "=" contiene otro "=" y, por ejemplo, se separa en 3 partes en vez de dos.

Comment: Me gusta esta respuesta. _El que sabe, sabe_

Answer (score 1):

Usando [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

```
   import configparser

   config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
   config.read('el_archivo')

   print(config.get('badge_name_ADM'))
```